# Data validation using selected rows and not a whole range of values

Tags: excel, validation

Currently i'm doing a data validation using the range `!$A$4:$A$76` and all is working great.

However, i'm trying to add something different, which is doing a data validation on the selected lines within that range. For example, instead of select all the lines between `!$A$4:$A$76`, i want to select `A$11, A$22, A$31, A$55, A$59, A$60, A$70, A$71, A$72, A$75`.

The method i was doing gave me an error in the data validation step, as long as it said: ' The source must be a delimited list or a reference to a single row or column '.

Can someone help me on this one?
Thanks for the help,
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not strictly possible. A workaround I would suggest is to use another range (perhaps on a hidden sheet) to reference the cells where the validation source is by using direct reference formulas. For example, in cell G1 you would write:

```
=$A$11
```

Then in Cell G2 you would write:

```
=$A$22
```

etc... then use the range G1:G10 as the source for your data validation list.

Comment: That's a nice way to work around. Thanks for the input!